how to insert a newline if yas-selected-text doesn't end with one
setup
given the following text
; indentation guides
(setq highlight-indent-guides-method 'character)

and this snippet
#+BEGIN_SRC ${1:elisp} :tangled
`yas-selected-text`#+END_SRC
$0

problem
If I have the full lines selected, all is good. and we end up with #+END_SRC sitting on its own line.
BUT if i have selected the characters, using my mouse, or some other method that hasn't captured the trailing newline, I end up with the #+END_SRC on the same line as the lisp code.
question
How can i insert an inline if the text in yas-selected-text doesn't end with one such that my #+END_SRC always ends up on a new line by itself.
And yes, I know I could just put a newline in the snippet before it and guarantee that but I don't want to have to delete that trailing blank line when I have selected text with a trailing newline.

The following answer works great, and came from رہگزر by way of mastodon‡.
#+BEGIN_SRC ${1:elisp} :tangled
`(if (string-suffix-p "\n" yas-selected-text)
     yas-selected-text
   (concat yas-selected-text "\n"))`#+END_SRC
$0

‡ They don't have an account here & I'm not sure they would like their account linked here, but I can't claim credit for this. ;)
